# Get nearest date column value from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B,

Table A

```
PstngDate   WorkingDayOutput
12/1/2020   221               
12/3/2020   327 
12/4/2020   509 
12/5/2020   418         
12/7/2020   390 
12/8/2020   431 
12/9/2020   244 
12/10/2020  246 
12/11/2020  314 
12/12/2020  301       
12/14/2020  411 
12/15/2020  530 
12/16/2020  554 
12/17/2020  300 
12/18/2020  375      
12/23/2020  402 
12/24/2020  302 
12/25/2020  269 
12/26/2020  382  
12/28/2020  608
```

Table B

```
 PstngDate  HolidayOutput   isWorkingDay
  12/2/2020     20              0
  12/6/2020     24              0
  12/13/2020    31              0
  12/19/2020    82              0
  12/22/2020    507             0
  12/27/2020    537             0
```

Expected output:

```
PstngDate   WorkingDayOutput    HolidayOutput
12/1/2020   221                     20
12/3/2020   327 
12/4/2020   509 
12/5/2020   418                     24
12/7/2020   390 
12/8/2020   431 
12/9/2020   244 
12/10/2020  246 
12/11/2020  314 
12/12/2020  301                     31
12/14/2020  411 
12/15/2020  530 
12/16/2020  554 
12/17/2020  300 
12/18/2020  375                     589
12/23/2020  402 
12/24/2020  302 
12/25/2020  269 
12/26/2020  382                     537
12/28/2020  608
```

I want to join TableB to TableA with nearest lesser date column. If you see Expectedoutput table, day 18 row of holidayoutput column is taking sum of day19 and day22 of table B.

Comment: How large is your data?  Is performance an issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to join TableB to TableA with nearest lesser date column

This sounds like a lateral join:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.holidayquantity, 0) as holidayquantity
from a
outer apply (
    select top (1) b.*
    from b
    where b.pstng_date >= a.pstng_date
    order by b.pstng_date
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self left join as follows:

```
Select pstng_date, workingDayQuantity,
       HolidayQuantity,
       workingDayQuantity + HolidayQuantity as total
  From
(Select a.*, b.HolidayQuantity,
        Row_number() over (partirion by a.psrng_date order by b.pstng_date) ad rn
  From tablea a join tableb b On b.pstng_date > a.pstng_date) t
Where rn=1
```